# Is it possible to formalize $T \models \sigma$ within the deductive calculus?

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic, incompleteness

I know that the notion of $T \vdash \sigma$ is formalizable within any
sufficiently powerful theory $T$ but is $T \models \sigma$
formalizable as well?  How is this possible if there are infinitely
many models (including uncountable ones) to consider?  And if it's not
possible then doesn't the completeness theorem contradict itself
because it is a true theorem which cannot be proven through the
deductive calculus?

Comment: You might want to look up [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski's_undefinability_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

To formalize a notion in a theory $T$ means to represent the notion using the language of $T$. When we do this we make a value judgment about the fidelity of that representation. If we are formalizing "syntactic" notions like $T \vdash \sigma$ in PA, our representions of syntax as numbers need to be faithful to our intuitions about syntax, but we tend to be fairly complacent about the representation of one kind of finitistic object as another. In ZF set theory, we can formalize the "semantic" notion $T \models \sigma$ and prove the completeness theorem for first-order logic. 
To do this, the representation of models as sets need to be faithful to our intuitions about models. We may be less comfortable with a language that can talk about things like uncountable sets, but the concepts involved in the definition of a model aren't difficult.

You may find it useful to read about Tarski's concept of a metalanguage http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/tarski-truth/. This lets you formalize the notion of formalization and eliminates the meta-level "value judgments" I mentioned above (but then gives you a meta-meta-level to worry about ...).

Answer (score 1):

Certainly semantic entailment is not something which can be directly talked about in $PA$ (although it can be in ZF); however, note that this does *not* contradict the completeness theorem. Completeness only says "any sentence which is a semantic consequence of $T$ *and is expressible in the language of $T$* is provable in $T$." This expressibility condition is crucial.

Comment: I would dispute your first sentence: derivability is not something that can be talked about directly in PA (PA talks about numbers not logical syntax); PA can also be used to talk (indirectly) about sets (which, in its standard model, are finite). So entailment can be modelled in PA, but the resulting model is less satisfactory than its model of derivability.

Comment: @RobArthan If you can only talk about finite models, you can't talk about models in any meaningful sense as far as the completeness theorem is concerned. Yes, PA can work with finite models, but that's not really relevant.

Comment: so how does PA talk *directlly* about syntax?

Comment: @RobArthan I consider Godel coding to be direct. Meanwhile, there is no coding mechanism whereby PA can talk about arbitrary structures, and finite structures simply *are not sufficient* for saying anything interesting in the context of the completeness theorem.

Comment: Let me put it another way: how would you phrase the completeness theorem in PA? Use as much Godel coding as you want . . .

Comment: I consider Goedel's encoding of syntax as numbers to be no less or more indirect than the usual encoding of sets as numbers via bitmaps ($i \in j$ iff the $i$-th digit in the binary expansion of $j$ is non-zero).

Comment: @RobArthan Sure, but that way **you can only capture finite sets**! How do you express the completeness theorem if you can only talk about finite structures?

Comment: I define $i \in j$ that way and then use that definition of membership to express a notion of entailment and the completeness theorem. Whether that is a satisfactory expression of the completeness theorem is a moot point (as I stated in my original comment) but I don't see how you can dismiss it.

Comment: @RobArthan OK, but then the version of the completeness theorem you can express is **false**: first-order logic is *not* complete for finite structures. (E.g. the set $\{$"there are $\ge n$ elements": $n\in\omega\}$ semantically entails $\perp$ for finite models, but obviously doesn't prove $\perp$.) I guess I don't call false statements satisfactory. I think we'll have to agree to disagree on this point, as well as whether it's moot (I think the OP is interested in the *actual* compactness theorem).

Comment: In particular, it's not that PA fails to prove some true things about entailment so codified, it's that it actively proves some false things.

Comment: of course the completeness theorem is false if restricted to finite structures. But it is absurd to dismiss statements that can be shown to be false as unsatisfactory.

Comment: @RobArthan I disagree as strongly as is possible. In my book, when trying to represent a true sentence in some different language, "false" pretty immediately implies "unsatisfactory." Regardless, I think this is not a productive conversation, so this will be my last comment.

Comment: You are conflating the notion of the sense of a statement with the notion of its truth. $1 = 2$ has a satisfactory sense, but happens not to be true. I am sorry that you found this exchange of comments unproductive, but you invited it in your answer by making claims about what PA "talks about".

Comment: @RobArthan OK, fine, *one* more comment: my point is **not** that the "completeness theorem" expressed in terms of finite models is not a satisfactory *sentence*, just that it's not a satisfactory *expression of the completeness theorem inside $PA$.* Think about it this way: "Hey, I expressed [X] inside [T]!" "Really? So, you found some [Y] in the language of [T] so that a reasonable theory can prove (something like) [X] iff [Y]?" "Well, no, *my* representation is actually provably false, even though [X] is true." I don't know about you, but I'd be pretty unimpressed with that.

Comment: @RobArthan Actually, I'm curious: what would you consider reasonable criteria for saying "[X] is an expression of [Y] in [T]"? Are there any requirements at all you'd put on this, and if so, how would they not be violated if one said "This false thing is an expression of this true thing"?

Comment: I'm just thinking about $\models$ here: the standard definition of $\models$ has very modest ontological requirements and has a clear meaning in any set theory in which one can construct products and power sets (e.g., the hereditarily finite sets, whose theory is equivalent to arithmetic). Given the negation of the axiom of infinity, the statement of the completeness theorem makes sense, i.e., it expresses the right notions, but it happens to be false. That doesn't make the statement unsatisfactory, it just points out that this set theory is very weak.